# How to filter out bars when the exchanges are not open?

Tags: pine-script

I have a pinescript here, and I'm trying to create a simple spread, but I find the spread I create includes times when security_1 or 2 is not open. How do I ensure that the spread as calculated below only includes values for when the exchange is open?

```
study("Spread")

security_1 = input(title="Security 1", type=symbol, defval="BINANCE:BTCPERP")
security_2 = input(title="Security 2", type=symbol, defval="BINANCE:ETHPERP")

security_1_close = security(security_1, period, close)
security_2_close = security(security_2, period, close)

spread = security_1_close - security_2_close
```

Answer (score 0):

This will only plot when both exchanges are active.

```
//@version=4
study("Spread")

security_1 = input(title="Security 1", type=input.symbol, defval="BINANCE:BTCPERP")
security_2 = input(title="Security 2", type=input.symbol, defval="TSLA")

[security_1_close, sec1_time] = security(security_1, timeframe.period, [close, time])
[security_2_close, sec2_time] = security(security_2, timeframe.period, [close, time])

spread = change(sec1_time) and change(sec2_time) ? security_1_close - security_2_close : na

plot(spread, "spread", color.yellow, style=plot.style_linebr)
```

Which yields:

[image: result]

Notice that the spread (yellow lines) are only plotted when TSLA (overlayed on main chart)
has data, so when both exchanges are open.